# Which HDDs/SSDs will be compatible with my Lenovo X201?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, thinkpad, compatibility

I'm thinking of replacing the HDD on my Lenovo X201. I'm willing to consider either new or used HDDs or SSDs, but I don't know what my constraints are. That is, what are the physical and software-based compatibility limits for HDDs/SSDs with my laptop model?

My current disk is a [ST9250315AS](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148489): Seagate Momentus, 2.5", 5400 RM, SATA  3GB/sec.

Can there be a mounting issue with SSDs which are shorter in height than my HDD?

Comment: @Ramhound: Really? No height, width or depth restrictions? No kind of BIOS limitation? If you're certain, make that an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound: No it isn't. It's the width. The height is under 1 cm (under 0.5")

Comment: They should be not physically larger than your current drive. If they are smaller then you may need to add padding, which could interfere with the thermals of the drive.

Comment: SSD come in 7mm or 9mm mostly so pretty much any SSD.  AlphaComp below says 9.5mm is max, so any hdd that height or smaller.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Padding, you mean, something like paper? Or foam?

Comment: @cybernard: And will I need brackets for those smaller drives?

Comment: Or a metal shim. Or a silicone pad. Lots of choices, some better than others.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Can you link to somewhere discussing such padding? Preferably with some photos?

Comment: @einpoklum  The 7mm ssd usually come with a 2mm shim, just in case.  Ask the vendor before purchasing if it comes with a shim.  https://www.amazon.com/EDGE-7mm-9-5mm-Spacer-Adapter/dp/B014LQM6I2

Comment: I wouldn't know of any. And I wouldn't recommend it either.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Ah... ok, I was under the impression you _were_ recommending it.

Comment: It is a valid method if one knows what they're doing, but I would not recommend it for general use.

Answer (score 1):

Official answer per lenovo support pages.

> 80 GB, 5400rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA Gen II interface 
>  160 GB,
>   5400rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA Gen II interface 
>  250 GB, 5400rpm,
>   9.5mm high, Serial ATA Gen II interface 
>  320 GB, 5400rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA Gen II interface 
>  500 GB, 5400rpm, 9.5mm high,
>   Serial ATA Gen II interface 
>  100 GB, 7200rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial
>   ATA Gen II interface 
>  160 GB, 7200rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA Gen
>   II interface 
>  200 GB, 7200rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA, FDE, Gen II
>   interface 
>  250 GB, 7200rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA, FDE, Gen II
>   interface 
>  320 GB, 7200rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA, Gen II
>   interface 
>  500 GB, 7200rpm, 9.5mm high, Serial ATA, Gen II
>   interface 
>  SATA 1.5Gb/s or 3.0Gb/s 
>   2.5" wide, 9.5mm high

Source: https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/pd010141

Comment: basically any 2.5" drive under 9.5 mm with support for sata 2. ssd would be fine but note that you wont experience the full speeds of the drive.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it'll be slower, but are you sure I won't have mounting issues due to a smaller height? Or need to get brackets or something?

Comment: some ssd's do match that exact size requirement, but if one you get doesn't match the height requirements, you can use some double sided tape to pack it out a bit, use on each of the length sides (perpendicular to the sata connector) at widths of 2-3mm to avoid overheating issues,. dont cover the middle or directly above the sata connector

Comment: as mentioned in the top of page comments some drives do come with shims, the first that comes to mind are the crucial mx300 ssds, they came with a "copy" of some hdd cloning software that i have completely forgotten the name of and a plastic shim that went around the entire top edge (or bottom) with some double sided tape to hold it in place.